# Add to Realm List only if doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I am trying to create a TV Series schema with a list of available Seasons (using RealmJS), I would like to not add duplicate season numbers to the `Seasons[]` list.

This is what I have:

```
TvSeries.schema = {
  name: 'TvSeries',
  primaryKey: 'mediaId',
  properties: {
    mediaId: 'string',
    seasons: 'Seasons[]'
  }
}

Seasons.schema = {
  name: 'Seasons',
  primaryKey: 'seasonNumber',
  properties: {
    seasonNumber: 'int'
  }
}

realm.write(() => {
  let season = realm.create('Seasons', { seasonNumber: seasonNumber }, true)
  let tvShow = realm.create('TvSeries', mediaObject, true)
  let seasonsList = tvShow.seasons
  seasonsList.push(season)
})
```

When I add a new episode (not shown here), it will add the TV Series data and Season again and as there are multiple episodes in a season, it will add to the `Seasons[]` list multiple times.

My thoughts would be to go through the `Seasons[]` list and check if it exists, if not then push a new season to it.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do a quick check to see if the list already contains the season before inserting:

```
realm.write(() => {
    let season = realm.create('Seasons', { seasonNumber: seasonNumber }, true)
    let tvShow = realm.create('TvSeries', mediaObject, true)
    let seasonsList = tvShow.seasons
    if (seasonsList.filtered("seasonNumber == $0", season.seasonNumber).length == 0) {
        seasonsList.push(season)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ast that works. Since the Seasons schema is just a list of possible season numbers (maybe a total of 20 objects), do you think it is a waste to have that in a seperate schema? Or is there some way to do something nested within the TvSeries schema?

Comment: I would still keep it as a Class, just for clarity and who knows if you would later need to add more properties to it. But it does not seem to need a primary key (it won't help for those small lookups, and maintaining the index is just overhead if not needed).

Comment: Thanks for your help.